# How do implement an Ajax partial page refresh within this block of code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am trying to refresh part of a page. More specifically, it is a division tag with a "class name". I am trying to keep things simple and to the point to avoid confusion. How would I add a partial page refresh to a single class within my current block of code? Please note that the code seems to be doing exactly what I want it to. I just need to add a partial page refresh to finish it off, but I have no idea how to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};
  that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    //console.log(value);
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

      data[name] = value;
  });

  //console.log(data);
  //now we are using ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      //console.log(response);
      //I think I would put the code for a page refresh here???
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--Ajax request with form element-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};
  that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    //console.log(value);
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

      data[name] = value;
  });

  //console.log(data);
  //now we are using ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#update-whole-cart').load(document.URL + ' #update-whole-cart');//make sure to include space before second id input
      $('.update-whole-cart-added-icon').load(document.URL + ' .update-whole-cart-added-icon');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

The problem was that I needed to filter out the data to only load part of the page with the contents I needed loaded. Thank you @MikeB for guiding me in the right direction. Another tip for anyone struggling is that you might need to put you desired part of page to reload in a separate class division and then for that new class division style it with a margin of 0 and padding of 0. The reason being is that if you do not add a new class once the Ajax request is completed it seems to move the element/class around to its original position I think. I don't know if there is a better way to do this but this is what worked for me. Hopefully my input can save you headaches. Context: this code is used to grab input data from a form element without whole page reload. Then the data is submitted and part of the page that needed to be reloaded, in this case the cart widget and my add to cart icon, was only reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using jQuery, you will need to add a param to your success function, eg:

```
success: function(data) {
  $(".my-div-class").html(data); // update all divs with this class
 }
```

This will take whatever your page returns (so ensure it is HTML) and update ALL div nodes class="my-div-class" with data.

If you used  in your parent page, you could use:

```
 $("#my-div-class").html(data);
```

instead.

Comment: I tried the first example you provided but it seems that it doubles the page I believe. The second line of code refreshes the whole page and then I have to manually refresh it again in order to see my cart item count number pop up. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond I truly appreciate it, but I would like to only refresh my cart icon and its contents

Comment: If you are seeing a double-page, it's because the page you are posting to is returning the ENTIRE page (ineffecient) and not just the data that you want to show in the div.  If that is the case, you could try PARSING the page to extract those fields..
success: function(data_page) {
  var data_piece = { write code to find ".my-div-class" and extract the value from data_page };
  $(".my-div-class").html(data_piece); // update all divs with this class
 }

Comment: eg: You could use data_page.indexOf("my-div-class") and parse that way.
A better way is to load data_page into a DOM object, then you can use jQuery to extract it.  Something like this:
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data_page, "text/xml");
data_piece = $(doc).find("#my-div-class")[0].val( );
[0] is because find returns an array, so take the first one.
Give that a try.

Comment: I am still a little confuse for the last example you posted as a comment. Am I suppose to declare that variable within the $('form').on('submit', function(){ .... here....} Then do the Ajax request the same as in your first answer you posted?

Comment: Before adding detail to the answer, does your $.ajax call return the ENTIRE page, or just the count of items in the cart?

Comment: It returns the entire page. I recently found the solution though. I just needed to change the information in the success part to only pull a certain part of the page.

Comment: Correct - Hopefully, you got that from my first two comment above.

Comment: another problem I ran into after doing this code is that my javascript stopped working. So the code is doing everything right, but now the javascript for the updated element is not working until I refresh the page :/. Do you mind giving me any tips?